# Error on Dropdown List

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, razor

I am trying to define a default value for my DropDown list as per another post on Stack Overflow as:

```
@Html.DropDownList(Function(model) model.Type, DirectCast(ViewBag.Type, IEnumerable(Of SelectListItem)), "None Selected", "No Payment")
```

But am getting an error of:

"Lambda expression cannot be converted to 'String' because 'String' is not a delegate type."

How to I achieve this so if nothing is selected in returns "No Payment".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, first, I think you must choose `DropDownListFor`, not `DropDownList`, if your first argument is an `Expression(Of Func(Of TModel, TProperty))`

In both case, there's no overload of `DropDownList/For` which takes 2 strings at the end, one for default text, and the other for default value.

If you do

```
@Html.DropDownList(Function(model) model.Type, DirectCast(ViewBag.Type, IEnumerable(Of SelectListItem)), "None Selected")
```

You'll get a null value for Model.Type when "None Selected" is the choosen option.

If you want to completely manage the default value and text, you'll have to add it directly to your `SelectListItem` (so in `ViewBag.Type`).

And use

```
@Html.DropDownList(Function(model) model.Type, DirectCast(ViewBag.Type, IEnumerable(Of SelectListItem)))
```

But not sure it's usefull. With other solution, you can check if "None Selected" has been selected by something like that (I do c#, forgive the syntax errors)

```
If Model.Type is Nothing Then
```